# Is there any way to type inline code in latex math mode in rMarkdown?

Tags: r, r-markdown

```
$\bar{X} = \frac{5+10+15}{3}= `r (5+10+15)/3`$
```

I was trying to type something like this, hoping to let R evaluate the inline code automatically inside latex math mode.

Comment: The RStudio preview doesn't work for that (because it doesn't run the R code), but it knits fine for me.